# Adding more condition to Vlookup

Tags: vlookup

I want to use vlookup formula with 2 scenarios:

Example:  I have sheet 1 with full data and Sheet 2 with other information. In sheet 2 I want to pull those records which exists in sheet 1 with vlookup. I have already wrote that query for vlookup. In same I want to add below conditions:

1) column c2,A2 & G2 of sheet2 are matching in any row of Sheet 1.

My vlookup formula is this:
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet3!$A$2:$J$20332,10,FALSE)

There are duplicate rows in column A and thats why it is not working as a primary key. Kindly share your thought.

Comment: can anyone please share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to construct a primary key by linking together all the information which will create a singular entry.

Given the limited info you provided I would go with creating in both sheets a new column with:

```
=A2&C2&G2
```

You could then do a vlookup based on this singular value and get the information from one sheet into the other.